# Can i inherit the operator>>?

Tags: c++

I have the following problem: let's say class `Item` holds the serial number of a product,
and class `Book` is an `Item` which inherits class `Item`'s serial number. I have to create and use `operator>>` for every class. I thought about creating `operator>>` to `Item`, and then just call it in the implementation of the `istream` of the book, but I don't know how.

The code goes like this:

```
class Item
{
protected:
    int _sn;
public:
    Item();
    ~Item();
    ...
    const istream& operator>>(const istream& in,const Item& x)
        {
        int temp;
        in>>temp;
        x._sn=temp;
        return in;
        }
};

class Book
{
private:
    char _book_name[20];
public:
    Book();
    ~Book();
    ...
    const istream& operator>>(const istream& in,const Book& x)
        {
        char temp[20];
        ////**here i want to use the operator>> of Item**////
        in>>temp;
        strcpy(x._book_name,temp);
        return in;
        }
};

int main()
{
Book book;
in>>book; //here i want to get both _sn and _book_name
}
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, `operator>>` has to be a free function or a `friend`, because the left-hand side is not of your class type. Second, the lhs must also be a non-const reference (because the stream changes state on extraction), the same goes for the second parameter (you change state, it needs to be non-const). With that in mind, here's how the operators should look:

```
class Item
{
protected:
    int _sn;
public:
    Item();
    ~Item();
    // ...
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Item& item){
      return in >> item._sn;
    }
};

class Book
  : public Item
{
private:
    std::string name;
public:
    Book();
    ~Book();
    // ...
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Book& book){
      Item& item = book;
      return in >> item >> book.name;
    }
};
```

Note that I changed your C-style string handling (`char name[20]` + `strncpy`) to a `std::string`, which is what you should be doing in C++.

It can be done even easier if you just implement a `from_stream` method:

```
class Item
{
protected:
    int _sn;
public:
    Item();
    ~Item();
    // ...
    virtual void from_stream(std::istream& in){
      in >> _sn;
    }
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Item& item){
  item.from_stream(in);
  return in;
}

class Book
  : public Item
{
private:
    std::string name;
public:
    Book();
    ~Book();
    // ...
    void from_stream(std::istream& in){
      Item::from_stream(in);
      in >> name;
    }
};
```

Thanks to `from_stream` being `virtual`, you never need to reimplement `operator>>`, it will automatically dispatch to the correct derived class depending with which it was called:

```
int main(){
  Item item;
  Book book;

  std::cin >> item; // calls operator>>(std::cin, item), them item.from_stream(std::cin)

  std::cin >> book; // calls operator>>(std::cin, book), converting book to its baseclass Item
                    // then calls Book::from_stream(std::cin), which in turn calls Item::from_stream(std::cin)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reuse an operator defined in a base class from a derived one, just add this in the derived declaration:

`using Base::operator>>;`

Answer (score 2):

Simply, no, not directly. `operator>>` can only sensible be member function for stream objects. For normal objects it should be a free function. If you define it as a member function then the class of which it is a member function effectively becomes the left operand and the other parameter becomes the right hand operand. You can't have a two operand form that is a member.

It is possible to use virtual functions in the implementation of `operator>>` to get polymorphic behaviour for `operator>>`, e.g.

```
class Base {
public:
    /* ... */
    virtual void FromStream(std::istream& is);
    /* ... */
};

class Derived : public Base {
    /* ... */
    virtual void FromStream(std::istream& is);
    /* ... */
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Base& base) {
    base.FromStream(is);
    return is;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You base class' methods like this:

```
void Derived::foo(args) {
    Base::foo(args);
}

// or

class Derived : public Base {

    int operator<<(int a) {
         Base::operator<<(a);
    }
}
```

`Base` is a name of a specific base class (you need to specify it because there could be more direct or indirect base classes).

`::` is the "scope operator". It means "Call the function `operator<<` from the scope of `Base`".

---

The above will probably be useful for you some time, but in case of this specific operator and this situation, (as @Xeo has pointed out, thanks!) the operator should be defined as a free function (a friend function perhaps), not a member function, because you only define `operator<<` or `operator>>` as a member function when you want it to take this class' object as its first parameter (left operand).

In case of `<<` and `>>` in the context of streams, conventionally the left operand is the stream, so you need a free function for this operator (a member function for `ostream` could work as well, but you would have to modify `ostream`, and you don't want to try that).

Comment: This won't work here, `operator>>` is not a base class member, but a free function.